# Java from a beginner

Tags: java, applet, awt

My daughter is creating a program for school, It's a story that lets the user determine the path of the story. I don't know java so I'm no help at all to her. I'm hoping someone can help me. She is having two issues. the first issue is in her programming below she has started to create a story and is asking the user to type Yes or No to her question. When she runs the program the applet won't let her type anything. The second question she has is if she wants to use an input again (she used the letters A,B & C in her first question and she wants to use them again later) how can she reset the input so the value is false? I really appreciate your help. Mike

```
    package story;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Story extends Applet implements KeyListener {

    Image mOffScreen;
    Graphics mOffG;
    boolean mAKey;
    boolean mBKey;
    boolean mCKey;
    String mBegining;
    String mBeginingTwo;
    String mPonyCorn;
    String mDragonpus;
    String mPear;
    String mBeast;
    String mYou;
    String mYesNo;
    String mName;
    public void init() {
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        this.setSize(1300, 700);
        mOffScreen = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        mOffG = mOffScreen.getGraphics();
        mAKey = false;
        mBKey = false;
        mCKey = false;
        mBegining = new String ("Once upon a time, in the village of Villagelandia, there was a terrible beast called the...");
        mBeginingTwo = new String ("A:Ponycorn-a pony and a unicorn-, B: Dragonpus-a dragon and an octopus-, C:Pear-a pig and a bear-");
        mPonyCorn = new String ("...Ponycorn. Don't let it's cute name and apperance fool you, it could gnaw off your head in one bite.");
        mDragonpus = new String ("...Dragonpus. It was probably the most ferice creature in all of Villagelandia and it could shoot fire out of it's tentacles.");
        mPear = new String ("...Pear. Despite it's fruity name it was a terrible creature who could kill you with one swipe of it's paw.");
        mBeast = new String ("This fearsome creature has destroyed all of the knights that the king has sent to defeat it.");
        mYou = new String ("But now the king has sent YOU to trap this beast. Can you do it?");
        mYesNo = new String ("Yes or No?");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics pG) {
        mOffG.setColor(Color.white);
        mOffG.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        mOffG.setColor(Color.black);
        mOffG.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(20f));
        mOffG.drawString(mBegining, 200, 300);
        mOffG.drawString(mBeginingTwo, 150, 400);

        if (mAKey == true){
            mOffG.setColor(Color.white);
            mOffG.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            mOffG.setColor(Color.black);
            mOffG.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(20f));
            mOffG.drawString(mPonyCorn, 200, 300);
            mOffG.drawString(mBeast, 200, 350);
            mOffG.drawString(mYou, 300, 400);
            mOffG.drawString(mYesNo, 600, 450);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("enter name");
            //mOffG.drawString("Enter name", 500, 500);
            //mName = in.nextLine();
        }
        if (mBKey == true){
            mOffG.setColor(Color.white);
            mOffG.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            mOffG.setColor(Color.black);
            mOffG.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(20f));
            mOffG.drawString(mDragonpus, 90, 300);
            mOffG.drawString(mBeast, 200, 350);
            mOffG.drawString(mYou, 300, 400);
            mOffG.drawString(mYesNo, 600, 450);
        }
        if (mCKey == true){
            mOffG.setColor(Color.white);
            mOffG.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            mOffG.setColor(Color.black);
            mOffG.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(20f));
            mOffG.drawString(mPear, 200, 300);
            mOffG.drawString(mBeast, 200, 350);
            mOffG.drawString(mYou, 300, 400);
            mOffG.drawString(mYesNo, 600, 450);
        }
        pG.drawImage(mOffScreen, 0, 0, this);
        repaint();
    }
        public void update(Graphics pG) {
        paint(pG);

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            mAKey = true;

        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_B) {
            mBKey = true;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C) {
            mCKey = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        /*if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            mAKey = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_B) {
            mBKey = false;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C) {
            mCKey = false;
        }*/

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably already know this but, just to make sure you do, doing this:

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

Means it will look for input in the console, so typing letters while focused on the applet will only trigger events if you press the A, B, or C keys. In case you don't know what the console is, if you use

```
System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

then "Hello World!" will be printed onto the console.

The reason It isn't letting you type anything in is because it never asks for an input (Other than the A, B, or C KeyListener input). The closest it gets is if you answer the first question with the A key, in which case it will create a scanner but never actually use it to scan the console input. Make sure the last three lines of all the if statements in the paint method are as follows.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter name");
mName = in.nextLine();
```

To set the value of a boolean to false, you just do boolean = false;
For example, to set mAKey to false, you can just do

```
mAKey = false.
```

Put that wherever you want to change mAKey back to false.